# What are .dat.nosyncb77b.* files and how to remove them?

Tags: xcode, xcode10

I am trying to remove the project directory but receive a **Permission denied for .dat.nosyncb77b.*** files. What are these files and how can I remove them?

After trying a number of different approaches to solve an Xcode issue with **Could not load authors for file 'Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj'** I have tried removing the whole project directory in an attempt to clone the project fresh from git.

However, when running **rm -rf project-dir** I got **Permission denied for .dat.nosyncb77b.** files. What is strange is that I am the owner of the files. I have tried changing the permissions to 755 and 775 but no luck. All the other directories and files were successfully removed apart from these .dat.nosyncb77b. files.

None of my other projects have those files. I have cloned the repo again under a different directory and could see that those files do not exist in the same **project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/username.xcuserdatad/** where those files are for that project.

Answer (score 0):

It could be ACLs preventing deletion, these are shown with the e option to `ls` eg `ls -le`   However I'd put money on the Locked flag being set, as I've encountered the occasional file with the Locked flag.

The easiest way to see this is to perform a Get Info (from Finder) on the files.
[image: General Get Info Panel]

In the General Panel and uncheck the Locked checkbox.

It can also be changed on the command line with the command `GetFileInfo` look at the `attributes:` line and look for the uppercase L, this means the locked flag is set. It shows as lowercase if unset.

```
file: "/Users/mark/Documents/20200605-pdftext/test"
type: "\0\0\0\0"
creator: "\0\0\0\0"
attributes: avbstcLinmedz
created: 01/30/2021 14:43:54
modified: 01/30/2021 14:43:54
```

To change the locked status use `SetFile -a l filename`